# Date Parser parsing every month to January

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have written following code to parse Date into this format `25 July, 2016`. This is what i have done to achieve this.

```
Date _date;
String datePattern = "dd MMMM, yyyy";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);    
String parseDate; 
            try {
                _date= formatter.parse(date);  //date Value is coming from serverin this format = 2016-07-21T16:01:57
                parseDate  = format.format(_date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The problem is that, all it converts all Months to `January` It converts this datet `2016-07-21T16:01:57` to 
`21 January, 2016`.

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
DateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); //time format from server
DateFormat dateFormatNeeded = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // time format needed
Date newDate = null;
try {
    newDate = userDateFormat.parse(date); // this parses server date format
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//this converts to required date format
String convertedDate = dateFormatNeeded.format(newDate);
return convertedDate;
```

Comment: yyyy-MM-DD is wrong, DD is day of year. it should be yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 4):

You have to match your parser pattern to the one that the server is sending:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); // this is fine now.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below for the first formatter

```
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```